# how to pass variables in query in c++

Tags: c++, mysql++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include </usr/local/include/mysql++/mysql++.h>
#include "/usr/local/include/mysql++/cmdline.h"
#include </usr/include/mysql/mysql_version.h>
int main(){
  int zipcode=2105;
  ostringstream strzip;
  strzip << zipcode;
  string strzipcode = strzip.str();

  mysqlpp::Query query = conn1.query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE FIND_IN_SET( 'strzipcode', `TableZipcodes`");
  if (mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult res1 =query.store())
  {
    cout << "We have:" << endl;
    for (size_t i= 0; i < res1.num_rows();i++)
    {
      cout<< '\t' <<res1[i][0]<<endl;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    cerr << "Failed to get item list: " << query.error() << endl;
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

When i run this code its giving me syntax error where i passes variable strzipcode in query. How to pass variable here. please help

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: So you have both ` and ' in your query?

Comment: The problem you are seeing is that in your string you are not getting the value of the variable 'strzipcode' but that literal string. You should look up how to use your library, you should be able to put a marker at the spot (usually a question mark) and then in a subsequent function call pass it a variable to go into that spot

Answer (score 1):

The root problem you are seeing is the query string

```
"SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE FIND_IN_SET( 'strzipcode', `TableZipcodes`"
```

When you compile your C++ code, that is nothing more than a string, the variables are not inserted as you seem to assume they would be.

A relatively simple, but bad, solution is to just concatenate the strings together, much like

```
"SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE FIND_IN_SET( '" + strzipcode + "', `TableZipcodes`"
```

Here we are using the actual variable `strzipcode`.

**PLEASE DO NOT DO THIS THOUGH!**

You really should be using what is known as *prepared statements*. I gave a quick look at that library you are using, but didn't see exactly how it should be done. But you would first do something sort of like

```
mysqlpp::prepare("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE FIND_IN_SET( '$1', `TableZipcodes`");
```

then later tell it what that place holder is

```
myPreparedStatment.setValue(1, strzipcod); // where 1 maps to the location of $1
```

Yes, the code I gave here is made up, you are going to have to now go and do the legwork to find out how to actually do this yourself. I also suggest you read up exactly *why* you would want to mess around with all this extra work.

**edit**

oh... just noticed that your initial query string is wrong in the very first place. You never closed the 'FIND_IN_SET' part. I'll leave it to you to work out how to fix *that* part.